# Ubuntu connects to wireless but doesn't work!

Tags: wireless, networking, connection

I just installed **Ubuntu 14.04 LTS** on my laptop, it connects to my wireless network and shows that it is connected, but when I try to load a webpage or do anything like download Steam for Dota 2, it doesn't work. When I try to connect my Facebook account to Ubuntu, it doesn't work. I want to be able to use Ubuntu with working Internet access. What do I do?.

```
ifconfig 

this shows up

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 88:ae:1d:60:56:eb  
          inet addr:192.168.1.13  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:16 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:24 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:24 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:1856 (1.8 KB)  TX bytes:1856 (1.8 KB)

When I type
ping askubuntu.com

this shows up
ping: unknown host askubuntu.com
```

Comment: Please do what is in the accepted answer in the link below so we may see the information needed to help diagnose the issue.
<http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-can-i-do>

Comment: What does `ifconfig` show? what does `ping askubuntu.com` show? What was your previod method of getting IP address: auto by DHCP or manual?

Comment: eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 88:ae:1d:60:56:eb  
          inet addr:192.168.1.13  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:16

Comment: lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:24 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:24 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:1856 (1.8 KB)  TX bytes:1856 (1.8 KB)


ping askubuntu.com
ping: unknown host askubuntu.com

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Comment: Either DNS or a network configuration error, the HW seems like it self-configured. Can you ping an ip explicitly? `ping 4.2.2.1` will ping one of Level 3s DNS servers.

Comment: I typed "ping 4.2.2.1" and it says "PING 4.2.2.1 (4.2.2.1) 56(84) bytes of data." Please help me figure out this problem so I can actually use this new Ubuntu setup :)! I am excited to become an Ubuntu user. Please help.

Comment: I've been waiting here with no answer, please, someone get back to me and help me solve this problem so I can actually use my laptop with Ubuntu.